# how to send JSON array to server with no AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i am trying to send an array of JSON objects to

PHP server using an hidden field

but all i am getting in the server is just a string

[image]

this is my javascript

```
function CreateArrayOfJSON()
{
      var all_childrens = $('#form_div').find('*');//get all root element childrens
      var form_elements = {
            elements: []
        };
            for(var i=0;i<all_childrens.length;i++)
            {
               var id='#'+$(all_childrens[i]).attr('id');         //get id
               var style_attr=$(all_childrens[i]).attr('style'); //get style inline
               var classes=$(all_childrens[i]).attr("class");

               form_elements.elements.push
               ({ 
                    "id"         : id,
                    "style_attr" :style_attr,
                    "classes"    :classes
               });
            }
            document.getElementById('form_elements_array').value=form_elements;//fill hidden field
}
```

this is my PHP:

this will return Object object (as in the picture above)

```
$form_elements=$_POST['form_elements_array'];
```

this will return null

```
$form_elements=json_decode($_POST['form_elements_array']);
```

any ideas ?

thank you

Comment: pass array instead of object... and serialize() it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('form_elements_array').value=JSON.stringify(form_elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

can you paste the output string ?

or alternatively

You can use Curl for the same

```
    $url = "URL Where you want to send data";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $attachment = array(
    'name' => 'Your first field',
    'link' => 'Second Field',
    'description' => 'description here',
);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

now php code on the receiver page

Answer (score 0):

can you paste the output string ?

or alternatively

You can use Curl for the same

```
    $url = "URL Where you want to send data";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $attachment = array(
    'name' => 'Your first field',
    'link' => 'Second Field',
    'description' => 'description here',
);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

now php code on the receiver page

```
        echo $_POST['name']; // get your data with POST method
```